# Laravel 4 Many to Many triangle with Eloquent, retrieve "suggestions"-like data

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

This might be very simple, but I can't find the solution... Any help will be appreciated.
I have 3 tables: **users**, **skills** and **projects**, all connected to each other with Many to Many relationship.

### **users <-- *MtM* --> skills <-- *MtM* --> projects <-- *MtM* --> users**

**User model**

```
public function skills()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Skill')->withPivot('level');
}
public function projects(){

    return $this->belongsToMany('Project')->withPivot('user_id', 'project_id');
}
```

**Skill model**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('level');
}
public function projects() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Project')->withPivot('level');
}
```

**Project model**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot('user_id', 'project_id');
}
public function skills(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Skill')->withPivot('level');
}
```

So, a Many to Many triangle. I want to get all the projects, the skills of which are ***subset*** of specific users skills. So basically "suggested projects" for user.

```
$projects = Project::whereHas('skills', function($q) use($array)
    {
        $q->thatAreSubsetOf($array);
        //$array contains names or ids of users skills
    })->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

If some `$user->skills` are 'PHP', 'C' and 'Javascript', all the returned projects skills should *only* be subset of those (e.g. *{'PHP', 'C'} or {'PHP', 'Javascript'} or {'Javascript', 'C'} or {'PHP', 'C', 'Javascript'} or {'PHP'}, or {'Javascript'} or {'C'}*)
 I've tried many thing, researched a lot in Laravel Docs/here but can't seem to get what I want..

Comment: Can you define your desired result, and also could you please add you model structure?

Comment: just done that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your requirement can achieve `Many To Many Polymorphic Relations`. Your requirement is to use skills with User and Project, so its would be easy to handle with `MTMPR`.

Example below shows how I have implemented sharing Skill with both Project and User.

**DB Schema**

Skill

```
id              integer
name            string
```

skillable

```
id              integer
skillable_id    integer
skillable_type  string
```

**Models**

Skill

```
class Skill extends Eloquent{
        public function projects(){
            return $this->morphedByMany('Project', 'skillable');
        }

        public function users(){
            return $this->morphedByMany('User', 'skillable');
        }
}
```

Project

```
class Project extends Eloquent{
        public function skills(){
            return $this->morphToMany('Skill', 'skillable');
        }
}
```

User

```
class User extends Eloquent{
    public function skills(){
        return $this->morphToMany('Skill', 'skillable');
    }
}
```

How to get skill from project

```
$project = Project::find($id);
$projectsSkill = $project->skills()->all();
```

And how you can get Project from skills

```
$skill = Skill::find(1);
$projects = $skill->projects();
```

If you still find something unclear to handle these situation, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to do this (even without Eloquent) with my setup? I've already created the sorting system, which sorts users by their skills. Now I need to do something vice versa.

Comment: well in that case, can you also define your schema structure, for product, user and skill. so i can manage to resolve it by query or php.